# React Native - Top bar navigation - Indicator

Tags: react-native

I want to acomplish this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNrP3.png ,

Current situation is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1rI5.png ,

I am unable to create that grayish line over every tab, and my actual orange indicator will go over that gray line when im moving thru my navigator.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Please share some code related to your issue. And it seems you created that component. I'll suggest you use  [https://reactnavigation.org/](https://reactnavigation.org/) to manage your navigation.

Answer (score 0):

At the end i figure out how to do it and here is an example if anyone have same problem :

```
 tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: getThemeColor("white", app.appTheme),
    style: {
      backgroundColor: getThemeColor("background"),
      elevation: 0,
      borderBottomWidth:_generalSize(1),
      borderBottomColor: getThemeColor('textInputPlaceholder'),
    },
```

I just put inside tabBarOptions style: and then i put normal border botom.